# How to rename an USB Disk - not the label

Tags: linux, usb, drivers, external-hard-drive

I tried to find a solution, but either is not possible or everyone is talking about the USB Disk's label.

Is it possible to rename an USB Disk? The name is something like "WD Ext HDD 1021" for a Western Digital external HD. On Windows can be seen under hardware properties. On Linux I'm not sure yet. I suspect it cannot be possible though.

I would like to do it because my silly Samsung TV has a veryvery annoying "feature" that memorizes the content of any HD and once you move files around, sometimes it doesn't see the new directories, sometimes it leave old files/directories around the path. Renaming the disk forces it to rescan the disk.

Comment: `WD Ext HDD 1021` is not the volume label, that is what the name of the device, the device is reporting to the OS.  You would have to modify the firmware of the device (I do not suggest you attempt this) to accomplish your goal.

Comment: @Ramhound oh ok thanks. Then I suppose I have to find another way to reorder my backup hd for the silly tv.